# pausing a "on-xxx-yyy-hook" script called by tortoiseSVN client-sided

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

### The Issue

We have a batch script which is called on post-commit-hook and post-update-hook. We would like to either pause the script or show the output if an error has occurred within the batch script.

Issuing a `pause` somewhere in the script will not result in a pause inserted when called from the hook.

Running the script normally will issue a pause.

Is it at all possible to issue a pause in a hook script? If so, how? Or are there other ways to display an error in a hook-script?

### What are the scripts supposed to do?

We would like to include the revision number of the current build within a xx_version.c file. This is needed so that our testers can perform their tests using a certain version and that we as developers can continue working on newer versions till they are finished with their tests and if there are any problems we can switch back to that revision and see if we can fix it. But that revision information needs to be stored in the software itself, even so that we can always go back to a certain revision if needed to fix 'things'. Testers will always use the 'nightly-builds' to test the soft- and hardware.

### Update 2012-11-16

We have made some progress, but quite in the wrong direction. We are using Eclipse as the IDE and we expected that the hooks would be executed when we would update/commit from within Eclipse. Sadly this is not the case. Thus we are looking in to other ways to automagically run these scripts. Preferable from within Eclipse when commiting/updating

Answer (score 0):

Preface:

- Eclipse SVN-integration doesn't related to TortoiseSVN and TSVN client-side hooks
- Any and every hook can write own log-file for reading this log later
- You can get HEAD revision of repository-tree dynamically, using `svn info URL`

If you really want and use client-side hooks, you have don't forget about hook settings in TortoiseSVN

[image]

While "Wait" haven't sense in you case, do not hide output window may be useful

PS: Maybe inside Eclipse you can start only usual SVN-scripts, in which **only exit-code** is usable